# with-redefs on functions used inside maps

Tags: clojure

I was wondering what is going on in the snippet below. Why isn't the function properly redefined without forcing the evaluation of the sequence?

```
user> (defn foo [] (map vector (range 3)))
#'user/foo
user> (defn bar [] (map #(vector %) (range 3)))
#'user/bar
user> (foo)
([0] [1] [2])
user> (bar)
([0] [1] [2])
user> (with-redefs [vector (fn [_] "what does the fox say?")] (foo))
("what does the fox say?" "what does the fox say?" "what does the fox say?")
user> (with-redefs [vector (fn [_] "what does the fox say?")] (bar))
([0] [1] [2])
user> (with-redefs [vector (fn [_] "what does the fox say?")] (vec (bar)))
["what does the fox say?" "what does the fox say?" "what does the fox say?"]
user>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that when you call `foo`, `vector`, as an argument to `map`, is evaluated (which in this case means resolving it to a function object) once and doesn't need to be resolved again. That same function object is used even after your code has exited `with-redefs`.

In `bar`, however, it isn't `vector` that's an argument to `map`, but instead an anonymous function which references `vector` by name. The result is that while the anonymous function is only evaluated once, `vector` will be resolved every time the anonymous function is invoked. Because `map` is lazy, that's happening after the code has already exited `with-redefs` (except for when your force evaluation).

The key point is that in a function call - like `(map vector (range 3))` - each of argument is evaluated and the calling function gets the *result* of those evaluations. That means the `map` call in `foo` gets the redefined `vector`, whereas the `map` call in `bar` gets a function which will still need to look up `vector` by name when it's invoked.

The Clojure.org [page on evaluation](http://clojure.org/evaluation) provides some details on how symbols are resolved to objects. This is also an example of [late binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding).